# Cannot visualize markers in rviz!

Tags: ros, rviz, skeleton-tracker, openni-kinect, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use openni_kinect and openni_tracker to track with kinect. Then, when a user is detected I can see the /tf in Rviz and it works.

However, when I try to use markers (eg. hone_markers, pointing_markers, ...) I see nothing in rviz. Topics are ok I think, because if I look rxgraph everything seems ok (rviz subscribed to topic /hone_markers, for example).

What should I do in order to visualize the markers in rviz?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12764/cannot-visualize-markers-in-rviz!/) by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the rostopic command to debug this. "rostopic echo /topicname" will print the topic data on screen. If this doesn't output anything, openni is not sending.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0